# Getting offsetHeight of a div by angularjs as 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to fetch the offset height of panel-footer in angularjs directive. but it always outputs as 0.

my  HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body pane-content-widefoot" set-height>
        Content                         
    </div>              
    <div class="panel-footer clearfix" >

            <button href class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn-fullwidth">Save</button>
            <button href class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn-fullwidth">Reset</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

my JS:

```
.directive('setHeight', function($window,$timeout){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var bodyHeight = $window.innerHeight*0.75;
            console.log('window height '+bodyHeight);
            var footerHeight = 0;

            console.log('footer height '+angular.element(document.querySelector('.panel-footer'))[0].offsetHeight);


            element.css('height',(bodyHeight-footerHeight)+'px');
            console.log('final body height '+footerHeight);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U39MJZxZiN3saHVT3hGw?p=preview)

Comment: apologies, left it there by mistake..i wa trying different things and left it there...

Comment: Agreed, console.log('footer height '+angular.element(document.querySelector('.panel-footer'))[0].offsetHeight); prints 0.

Comment: I am stuck with the fetching of offsetHeight which i will set the  footerHeight variable if the value is fetched properly.

Comment: I have gone through numerous fiddles but with no luck :(